# Problem in the derivation of the relation between $\sin^{-1}(x)$ & $\cos^{-1}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

**My book's derivation**:

Let, $\sin^{-1}x=\theta\implies \sin\theta=x$

Now, $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies\theta=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$

So, $$\fbox{$\theta=\sin^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$}$$

**My problem**:

My problem with this derivation is that $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is always positive. So, the principal value of $\theta$ will always remain in the 1st quadrant. So, for negative values of $\cos\theta$, we will not be able to determine $\theta$ accurately. So, how will I find the correct value of $\theta$ when $\cos\theta$ is negative? So, how will I find the correct value of $\theta$ when $\cos\theta$ is negative?

**Example of my problem:**

Let $\theta_1=\cos^{-1}(\frac{-4}{5})=\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{5})$ is in the 2nd quadrant, so $\theta_1=143.1301^{\circ}$, but according to the derived formula $\theta_2=\cos^{-1}(\sqrt{1-(\frac{3}{5})^2})=36.869^{\circ}$, so we can see that $\theta_1\neq \theta_2$ when they should've been equal. This formula can't differentiate between when $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is in the 1st quadrant or when it is in the second quadrant. How do I find the value of $\theta$ correctly when $\cos\theta$ is negative or is the formula so that I just can't?

Comment: Easy answer: you can't tell the sign. (Think that $\sin45°=\sin135°$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, to work with the inverse of the cosine function, we must devise a local concept that guarantees that such a function is bijective. Usually, for classic reasons, we define
$$\cos: [0,\pi] \longrightarrow [-1,1]$$
so that it makes sense to define $\cos^{-1}:[-1,1] \longrightarrow [0,\pi]$. That's why the principal value of the $\theta$ angle you mentioned is always in the first quadrant.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I couldn't understand you properly. How can $\theta$ be in the 2nd quadrant when $\cos\theta$ is always positive for the reason I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, when I mentioned $\theta$ I ended up explaining it right.  When the cosine is positive, it will always be in the first quadrant due to the good definition of the inverse.

Comment: So, how will I find the correct value of $\theta$ when $\cos\theta$ is negative?

Comment: Even if the cosine of $\theta$ is negative, it will be in the range $[-1.1]$.  That way, when we make the composition with its inverse, theta will still be in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: No, I understand that part. What I don't understand is that can we find the correct value of $\theta$ using this formula $\theta=\sin^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$ when $\cos\theta$ is negative?

Comment: Well, when you pass the square root on both members, we have an alternation between positive and negative signs...

Comment: It's like we have $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ and $\cos\theta=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$

Comment: I edited my question to explain my problem better. Could you please look into that?

Comment: Now I understand your problem.  Note that the formula will always give you angles in the first quadrant.  However, if the cosine is negative, you get the corresponding in the second quadrant.

Comment: in view of your example, just make 180° - 36.869° =143,1301° to reach the desired angle.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I hope I didn't disturb you too much.

Comment: The example helped to understand his problem. Good studies!